# count jumps from one location to another based on conditions

Tags: pandas, python-3.5, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe.

```
    id  start   finish  location
0   1   2015-12-14 16:44:00 2015-12-15 18:00:00 A
1   1   2015-12-15 18:00:00 2015-12-16 13:00:00 B
2   1   2015-12-16 13:00:00 2015-12-16 20:00:00 C
3   2   2015-12-10 13:15:00 2015-12-12 13:45:00 B
4   2   2015-12-12 13:45:00 2015-12-12 19:45:00 A
5   3   2015-12-15 07:45:00 2015-12-15 18:45:00 A
6   3   2015-12-15 18:45:00 2015-12-18 07:15:00 D
7   3   2015-12-18 07:15:00 2015-12-19 10:45:00 C
8   3   2015-12-19 10:45:00 2015-12-20 09:00:00 H
9   4   2015-12-09 10:45:00 2015-12-13 12:20:00 E
10  4   2015-12-13 12:20:00 2015-12-13 18:20:00 A
11  4   2015-12-13 18:20:00 2015-12-13 23:40:00 A
12  4   2015-12-13 23:40:00 2015-12-16 08:00:00 B
13  5   2015-12-07 08:00:00 2015-12-13 12:25:00 H
```

I wanted to calculate jumps from one location to another in every 'id'. For these jump counts, first I wanted to compare the date and time of finish column with the date and time of start column of the next row of the same id. If it matches, I want to have the count as 1 other wise 0.  What I want to obtain is the following:

```
    id  start   count
0   1   2015-12-14 16:44:00 1
1   1   2015-12-15 18:00:00 1
2   1   2015-12-16 13:00:00 0
3   2   2015-12-10 13:15:00 1
4   2   2015-12-12 13:45:00 0
5   3   2015-12-15 07:45:00 1
6   3   2015-12-15 18:45:00 1
7   3   2015-12-18 07:15:00 1
8   3   2015-12-19 10:45:00 0
9   4   2015-12-09 10:45:00 1
10  4   2015-12-13 12:20:00 1
11  4   2015-12-13 18:20:00 1
12  4   2015-12-13 23:40:00 0
13  5   2015-12-07 08:00:00 0
```

Once I have that, I would like to sum the counts based on date to get something like the following:

```
date    count_sum
2015-12-07  0
2015-12-09  1
2015-12-10  1
2015-12-12  0
2015-12-13  2
2015-12-14  1
2015-12-15  3
2015-12-16  0
2015-12-18  1
2015-12-19  0
```

For me, the last part is easy to do by doing groupby() based on date and using .sum() to sum up all the counts on that date. But how to get the first part where we count the actual jumps is not clear. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data already appears to be sorted by `'start'` so you can just `groupby` and check if the finish time is the same as the start time of the next row with `pandas.Series.shift()`

I'd advise against calling a column `'count'` as this is a built in function for pandas, so you can't use the `Series.col_name` notation.

```
#df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start)
#df['finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df.finish)
df['count'] = (df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.finish == x.start.shift(-1))
                 .astype('int').reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Output:

```
    id               start              finish location  count
0    1 2015-12-14 16:44:00 2015-12-15 18:00:00        A      1
1    1 2015-12-15 18:00:00 2015-12-16 13:00:00        B      1
2    1 2015-12-16 13:00:00 2015-12-16 20:00:00        C      0
3    2 2015-12-10 13:15:00 2015-12-12 13:45:00        B      1
4    2 2015-12-12 13:45:00 2015-12-12 19:45:00        A      0
5    3 2015-12-15 07:45:00 2015-12-15 18:45:00        A      1
6    3 2015-12-15 18:45:00 2015-12-18 07:15:00        D      1
7    3 2015-12-18 07:15:00 2015-12-19 10:45:00        C      1
8    3 2015-12-19 10:45:00 2015-12-20 09:00:00        H      0
9    4 2015-12-09 10:45:00 2015-12-13 12:20:00        E      1
10   4 2015-12-13 12:20:00 2015-12-13 18:20:00        A      1
11   4 2015-12-13 18:20:00 2015-12-13 23:40:00        A      1
12   4 2015-12-13 23:40:00 2015-12-16 08:00:00        B      0
13   5 2015-12-07 08:00:00 2015-12-13 12:25:00        H      0
```

And just for completeness:

```
df.groupby(df.start.dt.date)['count'].sum()
start
2015-12-07    0
2015-12-09    1
2015-12-10    1
2015-12-12    0
2015-12-13    2
2015-12-14    1
2015-12-15    3
2015-12-16    0
2015-12-18    1
2015-12-19    0
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is nice! I guess you'd either want to make sure `df` is sorted on `['id, 'start']` or use `.sort_index` after the groupby  so it doesn't mess with the row order?

Comment: Hi Alollz, Thanks a lot. It works out perfect. Yes the dataframe is already sorted out based on id and start. Thanks for the advise. I didn't know that using a column name 'count' can be problematic. From now on, I will keep myself away from using 'count' as column name.

Comment: Although your code works great, I do not understand how come lambda function in your code returns 1 if condition is met and 0 otherwise.  Would it be possible for you to explain how you end up in getting 1 and 0 in the count column? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HT121, Well the lambda function returns either `True` or `False` if the finish value is equal to the start value of the next row (the shift accomplishes the comparison with the row below). You then get `1` or `0` because I've used `.astype('int')`, which will convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`.